# Applying advanced filter in Power BI DAX, from a different table

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, advanced-filter

I have the following tables:

Episodes:
[image]

Clients:
[image]

My DAX calculation sums up [Days_epi] unique values, from Episodes tbl, grouping them by [ProgramID_epi], [EpisodeID_epi], [ClientID_epi].

So, the SUM of [Days_epi] = 3 + 5 + 31 + 8 + 15 + 20 + 10 = 92

Here is my working code for this:

```
     DaysSUM = 
       CALCULATE (
             SUMX (
               SUMMARIZE (
                  'Episodes',
                  'Episodes'[EpisodeID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[ProgramID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[ClientID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[Days_epi]
                  ),
                  'Episodes'[Days_epi]
             ),
             FILTER (
                 'Episodes',
                 'Episodes'[Category_epi] = "Homeless"
           )
        )
```

I need to add two advanced filters to the calculation above:

Filter 1 should ONLY KEEP records in Episodes,  if the records in the Clients have the difference between [DischDate_clnt] and [AdmDate_clnt] >= 365.

Filter 1 in SQL statement is

```
    DATEDIFF(DAY, [AdmDate_clnt], [DischDate_clnt]) >= 365)
```

After that, Filter 2 should ONLY KEEP records in Episodes, if the records in the Clients have
[Date_clnt] >= [AdmDate_clnt] + 12 months. (12 month after the Admission Date)

Filter 2 in SQL statement is

```
      [Date_clnt] <= DATEADD(MONTH, 12, [[AdmDate_clnt])
```

So, after applying those two filters I expect the records 6 and 10 of the Episodes tbl must be excluded (filtered out), because the records 2 and 3 of the Clients tbl (highlighted in green) are not satisfied my Filter 1 / Filter 2.

Here is the final Episodes dataset I should have (without the 2 records in red):
[image]

I was starting to update my DAX code as the following (below).
But keep receiving error "Parameter is not the correct type"

```
enter 
 DaysSUM_Filters = 
       CALCULATE (
             SUMX (
               SUMMARIZE (
                  'Episodes',
                  'Episodes'[EpisodeID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[ProgramID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[ClientID_epi],
                  'Episodes'[Days_epi]
                  ),
                  'Episodes'[Days_epi]
             ),
             FILTER (
                 'Episodes',
                 'Episodes'[Category_epi] = "Homeless"
           ), TREATAS(DATEDIFF('Clients'[AdmDate_clnt], 
                               'Clients'[DischDate_clnt], DAY)>=365,
                               'Clients'[Date_clnt])
          )
```

Not exactly sure how to set those 2 filters correctly in DAX Power BI, as I
am relatively new to it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say about all the case. But what is obvious is that you use `TREATAS` in a wrong way. It works like this `TREATAS({"Red", "White", "Blue"}, 'Product'[Color])`.

In your case

```
DATEDIFF('Clients'[AdmDate_clnt], 
                           'Clients'[DischDate_clnt], DAY)>=365
```

will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` value. The first argument of TREATAS - is a column or set of columns not a single value.

You can use the filter like this:

```
FILTER(
    'Clients'
    ,DATEDIFF(
        'Clients'[AdmDate_clnt]
        ,'Clients'[DischDate_clnt]
       ,DAY
    )>=365
)
```

This will return you a filtered table.
This may work if your tables are linked.

Comment: It finally worked. My problem was - I used non calendar type functions, trying to calculate numeric values. Should've just substract one value from another. The filters were correct. No need to use Treatas as well